# C# - Start process with different user using encrypted credentials

Tags: windows, encryption, registry, c#

This is the situation: I'm writing an application in C# that print a PDF, but the user that run this application can't access to the printer, so the printing process is started using an administrator user, where the credentials are stored in the registry of Windows, here the code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Security.SecureString ssPwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @" /t /h " + "\"" + fileName + "\"" + " " + "\"" + realPrinter + "\"";
proc.StartInfo.Domain = "";
proc.StartInfo.UserName = adminUser;
string password = adminPass;
for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
{
    ssPwd.AppendChar(password[x]);
}
password = "";
proc.StartInfo.Password = ssPwd;
proc.Start();

Thread.Sleep(1000);
proc.WaitForInputIdle();

proc.Kill();
```

This works perfectly, now I need to encrypt the password (maybe using MD5) in the registry in order to encrease the security of the application.
So I don't want to use SecureString to encrypt the password after reading it from the registry.

How I can do this?

Thank you,

Regards

Comment: MD5 is not an encryption. It’s a hash. It’s one-way. `ProcessStartInfo.Password` is a `SecureString`. No way around that.

Answer (score 0):

All encryption is only as save as the place you store the key in, so you only slightly moved the problem. The simplest solution would be to just *give the user those rights*. The first solution for rights issues, is to fix the rights.

If that is not an option, there might be another way that is not remotely as dangerous: [Interprocess Communication.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications).

You make two programms:

- The part the user is using
- a background process that runs as close to the printer as possible.

The background process starts with the proper rights do access the printer.
The local process has the minimum amount of rights it needs.
And two talk via IPC. No credentials in code, anything that is in the code is low danger (IP/Port pair or Pipe name) and you are still fully in the rights management.